Set a Default Term is not Allowing for New Terms to be Added
I'm trying to set a default taxonomy term for a post-type. It's working currently. Problem is if I try to add another term and hit save, it does not save.
Here is the code I created that is adding the default term to the post type:
if('non_profits_dir_ltg' == $post->post_type){
    
    $default_term = 'Non-Profits'; // Name of the required term
    $taxonomy     = "secondary-listing-category"; // slug of the taxonomy
    
wp_set_post_terms($post_id, $default_term, $taxonomy);
    
}

Am I missing something? How can I have both a default term and be able to add new terms to a post?

your code is triggering an error when added to my functions file. Can you provide more info on the context, where and how you insert this snippet? What's the full function?

@gael We have a custom post type that we are trying to give a all posts under that post type a default taxonomy term. This code above works to set a default taxonomy term, but it will not allow the addition of new terms if they are added and save on the post at a later date.
The code is placed in the functions.php of the active theme.
